# MongoDB Boolean Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I have a story collection of documents as below

```
[
    {
        createdBy:'user1',
        storyId:1,
        viewers:['user3'],
    },
     {
        createdBy:'user2',
        storyId:2,
        viewers:['user3'],
    },

    {
        createdBy:'user2',
        storyId:3,
        viewers:['user4'],
    },

    {
        createdBy:'user5',
        storyId:4,
        viewers:['user3'],
    },

    {
        createdBy:'user5',
        storyId:5,
        viewers:['user3'],
    }
]
```

Suppose user3 requests to get the status of each story of a specific user viewed by him or not. I want to return TRUE if the viewers array contains the user id of him('user3') in all documents and FALSE if any document not contains his userid in array. Hope you understand my question.

Expected Output

```
[
    {
        createdBy:'user1',
        isAllViewed: true
    },

    {
        createdBy:'user2',
        isAllViewed: false
    },

    {
        createdBy:'user5',
        isAllViewed: true
    },  
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- group by createdBy
- create an array of [true false ...] based on if `user3` is contained in "viewers"
- and then checks if in that array all are true

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SaOELr1LVu5)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdBy",
      "isAllViewed": {
        "$push": {
          "$in": [
            "user3",
            "$viewers"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "createdBy": "$_id",
      "isAllViewed": {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$isAllViewed"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I've just edited my anser using the same idea as you. I think is the best way. My first idea was using an auxiliar value and `$unwind` and then compare [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Irr3J_qulhL) but I switched to the approach using only one group. I've used `$setInteresection` (as I did previous to edit) but I think `$in` is a better way. Upvote to you.

Comment: its ok it , both are fine,he can see alternative ways, no worries , i did  bad project, i combined them now like in your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this aggregation query:

Using the same idea as before, use `$setInteresection` to know if `user3` is in the array. It produces an array with values `true` or `false` if exists or no.

So next stage is check `$allElementsTrue`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdBy",
      "isAllViewed": {
        "$push": {
          "$ne": [
            {
              "$setIntersection": [
                "$viewers",
                [
                  "user3"
                ]
              ]
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "createdBy": "$_id",
      "isAllViewed": {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$isAllViewed"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S8I-vMVORyl)

Comment: Please Make Slightly modifications.  I want to get results merged by createdBy(unique)  with all viewed true or false.

Comment: I think I haven't understood the question, can you add an expected output?

Comment: Updated my question with the expected output.